# Is there a non-vision example (like text-processing) done with Caffe?

Tags: caffe

Convolution Neural Networks can be used in Vision, NLP, etc. Now I want to know if there exists any non vision example, that anyone has done using Caffe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a nice NLP example [here](https://github.com/Russell91/nlpcaffe). There are much more, try searching for caffe + NLP or caffe + audio etc. in github.